# Why does this regex match the closing >

Tags: javascript, regex

For this regex:

```
/<(\/?)(\w+)([^>]*?)>/
```

on this string:

```
<div class='test'><b>Hello</b> <i>world!</i></div>
```

the match returned is:

```
<div class='test'>
```

I am confused at the `([^>]*?)` capture. Doesn't `^>` means that it is the inverse of `>`?

Comment: *sigh* stop trying to parse html with regex...

Comment: @PeeHaa Why not? In any case, I'm learning javascript syntax and this is an exercise from a book

Comment: Because most people are not able to write a working regex pattern to correctly parse html (as you found out). Even with the fix for your problem it will fail on other strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the breakdown of that regex:

`<(\/?)` matches the opening `<`, possibly followed by `/`

`(\w+)` matches many word chars (it's in parens so the capture group will contain the HTML element by itself)

`([^>]*?)>` matches multiple characters (lazily) that are not `>`, followed by a `>`

So in your example, it's correct that it matches `<div class='test'>`

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. The space between div and class threw me off